# Annotation argument error while using $slice in Spring MongoDB Repository with @Query in Kotlin

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I am using Spring Boot Kotlin with MongoDB. In this project, I have the one class which has an array attribute named pointsEntry. I have been trying to use the operator $slice to get only the first pointsEntry of all list when retrieving them in my own findAll method. This query works when tried in my Mongo client:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find( {}, { "pointsEntry" : { $slice: 1 } } )
```

However, I tried a similar approach in my Spring Boot project with the @Query annotation and it always gives error

> An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

```
@Query(value = "{}",fields = "{pointsEntry: {'$slice' : ?0}}")
fun findAll() : List<DocumentName>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing `'` single quote  on `pointsEntry` field

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'pointsEntry': {'$slice' : ?0}}")
```

Comment: i already done that but not working. But if i used same query in java class then it works fine.Issue is only with kotlin classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the $ sign

```
@Query(value = "{}",fields = "{pointsEntry: {\$slice : ?0}}")
```